# how to publish a 3rd party library to support both angular 2 and angular4

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using a 3rd party library for Angular. Initially it is supported in Angular 2. For the Upgraded versions of Angular(Angular 4 and Angular 5), how will i publish a 3rd party library to support for All versions of Angular?

Comment: is this any error you are getting while publishing it ?..

Comment: Are you **using** that library ? or **publishing** it ?

Comment: Yes. Am Publishing a library and using in my application

Answer (score 0):

If the codebase is identical, just publish your library and mention Angular dependencies with `^2.0.0` in your `peerDependencies`.

If the codebase is different for the different versions of Angular, maintain different versions. I suggest to use the corresponding Angular versions as your version number, so for instance your 2.x version will be for Angular 2, 4.x for Angular 4 and 5.x for Angular 5.

And in your `peerDependencies`, mention the Angular dependencies with ranges, like `>=4.0.0 <5.0.0`.